# TDD applied only to model or elsewhere

Tags: java, android, node.js, unit-testing, tdd

I've bought "TDD by example" from Kent Beck and I've read the first part, concerning the Money conversation and computation.

Before reading further, I had some questions.

*Is TDD related only to the domain specific part ?*

**My context is the following**

- I m a nodejs developper and I work on REST API. In nodejs we use route callbacks (just like controllers) and I was wondering if I have to make some integration test when dealing with TDD ? Or should I only apply it to my service / repository / entities ? (I know that I have to make integration tests, but I was wondering how it can be applied with the TDD principles, that I found really domain oriented)
- When dealing with mobile dev (in my case Android native), activities (that acts like controllers) are not concerned by the TDD way of work right ? Cause it implies integration tests too I think ?

Answer (score 1):

TDD is not just about Unit tests, it's a general approach to developing software. There's a popular practice of starting work on a certain feature by first writing failing acceptance tests, which should be readable enough to describe what that feature achieves. Then you proceed with writing Unit tests for all relevant classes, following the Red-Green-Refactor cycle. At the end of development you should have both your Unit tests passing, and the acceptance tests for the feature passing as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try to see wider so. But there's always something that I cant understand. How can I create a scenario concerning a GET request on a /users ressource ? (integration testing) with TDD practice ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with writing integration and acceptance tests for web services, but on a high level - write a test that accesses the resource like a normal client would do, make sure that it fails, then continue with writing unit tests for the classes.